# How to describe flavor but not texture

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word to denote the flavor of something while explicitly not including texture, which is usually assumed (eg "This tastes good" usually means you like both the <word I'm looking for> and the texture)

For example:

> This drink _______________ of strawberries, while still being a cool, smooth liquid.

Comment: I don't think "taste" does include the texture. Why do you think it does?

Comment: @sumelic My impression is that it sometimes does, depending on context. If I was given a strawberry in sludge form and didn't like it, I would not say "This tastes good", I would instead say something like "I like the taste but not the texture". This is why I'm looking for something that *explicitly* leaves out texture.

Comment: Just as a point of note, your wording "...while still being..." is interpreted as meaning that "having the flavor of strawberries" would somehow imply that this would not be a cool, smooth liquid.  But they really don't have anything to do with each other. For example, "This drink has the flavor of chunky beef stew, while still being a cool smooth liquid"  while sounding disgusting uses the phrases correctly.  You might be better off  with: "This cool, smooth drink has the flavor of strawberries right off the vine."

Comment: Sorry to disagree with you, but "This tastes good" does not automatically include texture, nor would I assume that if someone said they liked the taste of something.

Answer (score 2):

Your own description includes the correct word: "flavor."

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavor

"This drink **has the flavor of** strawberries, while still being a cool, smooth liquid."